# How can limit imaged-changed checkbox counts in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to limit selected checkbox which changed to image.
but when I change to image, I cannot do this(I already can limit it in basic form)
How can I do this??

```
$('.subscriber :checkbox').change(function () {
var $cs=$(this).closest('.subscriber').find(':checkbox:checked');
if ($cs.length > 3) {
    alert("false");
    this.checked=false;
}

$('.input_class_checkbox11').each(function(){
$(this).hide().after('<div class="class_checkbox" />');}

$('.class_checkbox').on('click',function(){
$(this).toggleClass('checked').prev().prop('checked',$(this).is('.checked'))}

$('.input_class_checkbox12').each(function(){
$(this).hide().after('<div class="class_checkbox1" />');}

$('.class_checkbox1').on('click',function(){
$(this).toggleClass('checked').prev().prop('checked',$(this).is('.checked'))}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think also that the code is not formatted well. Does `$('.input_class_checkbox12').each` should run inside `$('.input_class_checkbox11').each`? (For example)

Comment: each checkbox is seperate